# unqualified id error and tic tac toe board not working

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to write a C++ tic tac toe game. however I keep getting two errors. 
1. before each of my two if states after the while loop I get the error "unqualified-id before 'if'". I am not sure why. 2. when i run the program it automaticaly says invalid move, it does not replace the space on the board with an x or o. Please help, here is my code:

```
/*
Sophia Ali
   Template for TicTacToe.cpp (CS-509 Assignment 5)
can't get program to store x and o in the board
*/

#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

/*
   Game status enumeration
*/
enum Status { WIN, DRAW, CONTINUE, QUIT };

/*
   Function prototypes
*/
// showBoard: Show current state of board
void showBoard( const char board[], int boardSize );
// checkGameState: Returns WIN or CONTINUE
Status checkGameState( const char board[] );
int getHumanSquare( const char board[] );
int getComputerSquare( const char board[] );
// checkBadSquare: Checks to see if a chosen square is already taken; returns
//                 true if already taken; used by getHumanSquare and
//                 getComputerSquare functions above.
bool checkBadSquare( const char board[], int squareNum );
int getrandint( int min, int max );

int main()
{
    char board[] = "123456789";   // 10 element char board
    const int boardSize = 10;
    Status gameState = CONTINUE;
    int gametype, squareChoice, turnNum = 0;
    char currentSymbol;           // 'o' or 'x'

    cout << "\n This is a Tic Tac Toe program. Choose the type of game: "
         << "\n (1) human o vs. human x    (2) human o vs. dumb computer x"
         << "\n\n -> ";
    cin  >> gametype;

    /* Show the current state of Tic Tac Toe board. */
    cout << gameState;
    cout << "\n\n";

    /*
       Main game loop
    */
    while ( gameState == 2 )
    {
        /* Increment turnNum by 1. */
        turnNum++;

        /* If turnNum equal to 10
              Set gameState to DRAW.
              Break out of while loop. */
        if ( turnNum == 10 )
        {
            gameState = DRAW;
            break;
        }
        /* If we are on an odd-numbered turn
              Print "It's o's turn."
              Set currentSymbol to 'o'.
              Call getHumanSquare function to get squareChoice.*/
        if ( turnNum%2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "It's o's turn.";
            currentSymbol = 'o';
            cout << "\n\n";

            getHumanSquare(board);
            showBoard( board, boardSize );
        }

        /* Else (we are on an even-numbered turn)
            Print "It's x's turn."
            Set currentSymbol to 'x'. */
        else
        {
            cout << "It's x's turn.";
            currentSymbol = 'x';
            cout << "\n\n";
            showBoard( board, boardSize );

        }

        /*   If the gametype is 1 (human vs. human)
              Call getHumanSquare function to get squareChoice.*/
        if ( gametype == 1 )
        {
            getHumanSquare(board);
        }

        /* Else (gametype is 2 (human vs. computer))
           Call getComputerSquare function to get squareChoice. */
        else
        {
            getComputerSquare(board);
        }

        /* If squareChoice is -1 (human player quit)
              Set gameState to QUIT.*/
        if ( squareChoice == -1 )
        {
            gameState = QUIT;
        }

        /* Else
           Insert currentSymbol into board at (squareChoice - 1).
           Show the current state of the Tic Tac Toe board.
           Call checkGameState function to determine the gameState. */
        if (squareChoice >= 0 && squareChoice <= 8 && board[squareChoice-1] == '0' + squareChoice)
        {
            board[squareChoice-1] = currentSymbol;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"Invalid move";
            turnNum--;
            cout << "\n\n";
        }
        checkGameState(board);
    }
    return 0;
}/* end while*/

/* If gameState is WIN
      print "Player " currentSymbol " is the winner." */

if ( gameState == WIN)
    cout << "Player" << currentsymbol << "is the winner.";

/* If gameState is DRAW
      print "It's a draw." */
if ( gameState = DRAW )
cout <<"It's a draw.";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void showBoard( const char board [], int size )
{
    cout << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size ; i++ )
    {
        cout << board[ i ] << " ";
        if ( ( i + 1 ) % 3 == 0 )
            cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Status checkGameState( const char board[] )
{
    // Board       Array
    //
    // 1 2 3       0 1 2
    // 4 5 6  -->  3 4 5
    // 7 8 9       6 7 8
    //
    // Diagonal winners
    if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 0 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 2 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 6 ] )
        return WIN;
    // Horizontal winners
    else if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 1 ] && board[ 1 ] == board[ 2 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 3 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 5 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 6 ] == board[ 7 ] && board[ 7 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    // Vertical winners
    else if ( board[ 0 ] == board[ 3 ] && board[ 3 ] == board[ 6 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 1 ] == board[ 4 ] && board[ 4 ] == board[ 7 ] )
        return WIN;
    else if ( board[ 2 ] == board[ 5 ] && board[ 5 ] == board[ 8 ] )
        return WIN;
    else
        // No one has won yet
        return CONTINUE;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getHumanSquare( const char board[] )
{
    int squareNum;

    cout << "\n Input the number of an empty square: (-1 to quit) ";
    cin  >> squareNum;

    while ( checkBadSquare( board, squareNum ) == true )
    {
        cout << "\n Bad input. Choose another square: ";
        cin >> squareNum;
    }

    return squareNum;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getComputerSquare( const char board[] )
{
    int squareNum;

    squareNum = getrandint( 1, 9 );

    while ( checkBadSquare( board, squareNum ) == true )
    {
        squareNum = getrandint( 1, 9 );
    }

    return squareNum;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool checkBadSquare( const char board[], int squareNum )
{
    int realSquareNum = squareNum - 1; // count from 0

    if ( squareNum == -1 )
        return false;  // Let quit code pass as a valid square
    else if ( squareNum > 9 )
        return true;   // Square numbers out of range are invalid
    else if ( board[ realSquareNum ] == 'o' || board[ realSquareNum ] == 'x' )
        return true;   // Already taken squares are invalid
    else
        return false;  // Valid square number
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int getrandint( int min, int max )
{

    int scale, shift;
    scale = max - min + 1;
    shift = min;
    return rand() % scale + shift;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Indent your code properly. If you had you could have seen why the first error appears **easily**. Second pay attention to letter cases.

Comment: @stardust_ I checked the letter cases again in the code
 if (squareChoice >= 0 && squareChoice <= 8 && board[squareChoice-1] == '0' + squareChoice)
        {
            board[squareChoice-1] = currentSymbol;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"Invalid move";
            turnNum--;
            cout << "\n\n";
        }
        checkGameState(board);
 but it still did not work. I also changed it to an else if to test it, but no luck

Comment: It didn't work means it doesn't give the intended answer? or it doesn't compile at all?

Comment: Your questions are 1. It doesn't compile **and** 2. It gives the wrong answer when it's run.  How are you running C++ code that wasn't compiled?

Comment: What is the error? what does it say? because I moved the if's into main fixed the cases and it compiled properly. But of course it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: It is compiled and the program runs. however when the part comes for the user to choose a square no matter what number the user chooses it skips to the else state which is invalid move. I cannot get it to change the number to an x or o on the board

Comment: @user2085224 Please make sure that the code in your question is correct.  The code you've posted can not compile.

Answer (score 4):

Your first comment here is incorrect.

```
    }
    return 0;

}/* end while*/


/* If gameState is WIN
      print "Player " currentSymbol " is the winner." */

if ( gameState == WIN)
    cout << "Player" << currentsymbol << "is the winner.";
```

What you call `/* end while */` is actually the end of `main()`.  The `}` that you see above it is the *real* end of your `while` loop.

The error is telling you that you're writing code outside of a function.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Drew is suggesting that you need to figure out what is wrong with your braces. Executable code (such as an if statement) must be inside a function. Since the compiler thinks `main()` ends where the comment says "end while", the if statement causes an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax problem**

```
if ( gameState == WIN)
cout << "Player" << currentSymbol << "is the winner.";

/* If gameState is DRAW
print "It's a draw." */
if ( gameState = DRAW )
cout <<"It's a draw.";
```

Should be inside main.. (I think) right now it is out in the global scope.

---

**Logical problem**

with your code is probably on the line

```
if (squareChoice >= 0 && squareChoice <= 8 && board[squareChoice-1] == '0' + squareChoice)
```

This need to be properly parenthesized. And what do you mean by

```
&& board[squareChoice-1] == '0' + squareChoice
```

comment it please.

Comment: by
 && board[squareChoice-1] == '0' + squareChoice

i mean if squarechoice -1 is equal to 0+squareChoice. because squareChoice-1 is the number of the box, and 0+squareChoice would be what the user has chosen.

Comment: `'0' + squareChoice`  is not what you want then. Maybe `0 + squareChoice`but that is just `squareChoice`

Comment: would it be easier if i used this instead:
else
        {
            if (squareChoice == 1 && board[1] == '1')
            board[1] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 2 && board[2] == '2')
            board[2] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 3 && board[3] == '3')
            board[3] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squareChoice == 4 && board[4] == '4')
            board[4] = currentSymbol;
            else if (squarechoice == 5 && board[5] == '5')
and so on for every board number?

Comment: Ahh I see. :) `'0' + 1 is not equal to '1'`

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand.

Comment: BTW where you are you reciving the `squareChoice`? from the user. You ask for it but you have no `cin>>squareChoice` to accept it.

Comment: `squareChoice = getHumanSquare(board);` you need this not just `getHumanSquare(board);`

Comment: I think squarechoice was supposed to be squarenum because below it asks for squarenum but squarechoice is never used. but even still no matter what i do the board does not change to x or o it just skips that and goes to invalid move